# Hypergeometric Function simplification

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

Is there a way to simplify anyhow (also taking some limits of big/small parameters) the following hypergeometric function $_2F_1(1,-a,-a-b,1)$ for integer values of both $a$ and $b$ ?

Comment: If $\{a\in \mathbb{Z},b\in \mathbb{Z},a>0,b>0\}$ is: $\, _2F_1(1,-a;-a-b;1)=1+\frac{a}{1+b}$

Comment: how can I prove that ?

Comment: `Mathematica` and `Maple` says that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Chu-Vandermonde identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chu-VandermondeIdentity.html) (a special case of [Gauss's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssHypergeometricTheorem.html)) in the case of $a$ a positive integer, we have

$$\begin{align*}
{}_2 F_1\left({{-a,1}\atop{-a-b}}\middle|1\right)&=\frac{(-a-b-1)_a}{(-a-b)_a}\\
&=\frac{\frac{(-1)^a(a+b+1)!}{(b+1)!}}{\frac{(-1)^a(a+b)!}{b!}}=\frac{a+b+1}{b+1}
\end{align*}$$